# jQuery selector for li whose first child is a span

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

here is an HTML structure I can't change:

[image]

I successfully attached a click event handler for those `li`'s, like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu li.top-level", function (e) { 

     // whatever code

});
```

However, I don't want the clicks on `li`'s that have the `z-index: auto` to be caught by the handler. I tried this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu li.top-level[style='z-index: auto;']", function (e) {
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu li[style='z-index: auto;'].top-level", function (e) {
```

but no luck.

Also, the `li`'s I want to catch in the handler have a `<a>` as first child, while the others have a `<span>`. Maybe this can be used to help?

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML structure: I want to catch the upper `li`, not the other one

[image]

Comment: I think you need `:not()` i.e. `"#menu li.top-level:not([style='z-index: auto;'])"`

Comment: What @Satpal said - it seems you have your criteria backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first child of the `li` elements you want is guaranteed to be an `a` while that of the ones you don't is always a `span`, you're better off selecting based on that condition instead since matching elements by their styles is often fragile:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu li.top-level:has(> a:first-child)", function (e) {
```

Comment: @chiapa: If anything your edit suggests that that's not supposed to happen at all and that my answer should work.

Comment: You are right, I was forgetting the last parenthesis. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you don't want to select element having `style='z-index: auto;'` then use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to target element having anchor as first child

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu li.top-level:not([style='z-index: auto;']):has(> a:first-child)", handler);
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#menu li.top-level:not([style='z-index: auto;']):has(> a:first-child)", function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="top-level"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="top-level"><span>2</span></li>
  <li class="top-level" style='z-index: auto;'><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```